# Why does binary search work for this unsorted array?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, binary-search

**Given this question:** 
A peak element is an element that is greater than its neighbors.

Given an input array where num[i] ≠ num[i+1], find a peak element and return its index.

The array may contain multiple peaks, in that case return the index to any one of the peaks is fine.

Example: Array = [1, 4, 5, 7, 4, 3, 1]. Peak Index = 3 (i.e. 7).

The following code works perfectly (not just for this test case):

```
    public static int getPeakElement(int[] array, int left, int right) {

    if (left == right) {
        return left;
    }

    int mid = (left + right) / 2;

    if (array[mid] > array[mid + 1]) {
        return getPeakElement(array, left, mid);
    }

    return getPeakElement(array, mid + 1, right);
}
```

I don't understand how it can work - I thought binary search was just for sorted arrays / rotated arrays.

Comment: Probably because the peak just happens to be in the middle. Try swapping, say, 5 and 7, and it won't work any more.

Comment: That you get correct results is just a coincidence. Try an array like `1, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 7 ` and you'll get index 2 instead of 6.

Comment: @Thomas index 2 is correct in that case, since `5` is *one* of the peaks.

Comment: @luk2302 I see, but then it's not binary search anymore (at least not the sort that finds you _a specific_ element). So it's probably more a letter of misunderstanding on the OP's side on what the code is meant to do.

Comment: @AndyTurner the code actually works with 5 and 7 swapped, the retuned index is 2 in that case.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thomas & luk2302 - thanks for your input guys. Yes, in the example [1, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 7 ], index of 2 is a correct answer as Thomas pointed out...

Comment: I think that it works just because you have to find a peak, not the greatest peak.

Comment: The key requirement that I missed was *"num[i] ≠ num[i+1]"*, that is very important.

Comment: @RachelSlater the algorithm doesn't work well, sometimes it throws exception,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the definition of a "peak" is simply that it is an element larger than the surrounding elements, then you can reason about why it works.

```
if (array[mid] > array[mid + 1]) {
    return getPeakElement(array, left, mid);
}

return getPeakElement(array, mid + 1, right);
```

The condition is saying:

- If the mid element is bigger than the adjacent element, it might be the peak - it is certainly bigger than the element on its right. Search within the "left hand" half for a peak which is at least as big.
- Otherwise, the adjacent element might be the peak - it is certainly bigger than the element on its left. Search in the "right hand" half for a peak which is at least as big.

As the recursion progresses, you know that:

- `left-1` is outside the array, or the element there is less than the element at `arr[left]` (otherwise you wouldn't have chosen this half)
- `right+1` is outside the array, or the element there is less than the element at `arr[right]` (otherwise you wouldn't have chosen this half).

You continue until `left == right`, at which time you know you've reached the peak, because the adjacent elements are less (or you're at one end or other of the array).

Answer (score 2):

If there are multiple peaks then the array doesn't need to be sorted. Sorting would actually remove all but one peak.

How does this code work? Imagine you're on an uneven road and need to find a peak - but you're blind so you can't see it and have to work by feeling only. You start at some point and check whether you have to go left or right depending on the slope of the point you're at (you put a foot left and right and feel what you hit). Then you take a big step (you're [Miss Fantastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Fantastic) so huuge steps are not a problem for you) and check the slope at the new location again. You repeat that with decreasing step sizes until you reach a point where left and right are downhill, so you've reached a peak.